# Vetur/Prettier format classes in every line

Tags: prettier, vetur

I have 2 document formats for `.vue` files: Vetur and Prettier.

Both, formated my `attr` `class` like:

```
class="
  inline-block
  py-5
  px-2
  text-gray-300 text-sm
  uppercase
  font-light
"
```

But I prefer:

```
class="inline-block py-5 px-2 text-gray-300 text-sm uppercase font-light"
```

I changed the Width

```
"prettier.printWidth": 300
```

But same result

How can I disable that option?

Answer (score 0):

After read [#10918](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918)

The only solution that works was a downgrade to [v6.3.2](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/releases/tag/v6.3.2)